# Count Google News search results

Tags: python, api, search

I'm trying to programmatically get a count of Google News search results (i.e. how many results) for a list of search terms, but only for the last 1 year. Searching with the user interface, a results count appears only in the regular search, but doesn't appear when going under "Tools > Recent > Past Year". I tried the code below in python (to first return search results count for google news, without the 'last 1 year' filter, but there is a problem with it- it reports a wrong results count. For example, going to Google news and searching for Apple, yields 321 million results:
https://www.google.com/search?q=apple&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj81ojfheLfAhXE_SwKHRuNByUQ_AUIDygC&biw=1600&bih=696
But the code below reports 415 million results.

So how can I do this, and also later limit the count for results in the last year? it doesn't have to be in python, of course.

Many thanks.

The python code:

```
import requests
enter code here`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Get Google Count.')
parser.add_argument('word', help='word to count')
args = parser.parse_args()

r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/search',
                 params={"client":"firefox-b-ab",
                         "tbm":"nws",
                         "ei":"Oj02XIiCO6-V1fAP9d-j0AY",
                       'q':'"'+args.word+'"',
                       'oq':'"'+args.word+'"',
                       "tbs":"li:1"}

                )

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
print (soup.find('div',{'id':'resultStats'}).text)
```

An inaccurate Google news count.

Comment: why not use the google news api rather than parsing the results? https://newsapi.org/s/google-news-api

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Get Google Count.')
parser.add_argument('word', help='word to count')
args = parser.parse_args()

r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/search',
                 params={"client":"firefox-b-ab",
                         "tbm":"nws",
                         "ei":"Oj02XIiCO6-V1fAP9d-j0AY",
                       'q':'"'+args.word+'"',
                       'oq':'"'+args.word+'"',
                       "tbs":"li:1"}

                )

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
print len((soup.find('div',{'id':'resultStats'}).text))
```